# looking for a way to strip a trailing comma from string only if one is there php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - Remove last character if it’s a period?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/php-remove-last-character-if-its-a-period)

I am trying to strip a trailing comma from a string.  I do it like this:

```
$_POST['city_id_list'] //looks like 1,4,213,
$trimmed = substr(trim($_POST['city_id_list']),0,-1);
```

But what if the last character is not a comma?

java has something like:

```
str.replaceAll(" ,$", "")
```

I assume there is a way to do this with PHP.  What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function:

```
$trimmed = rtrim($_POST['city_id_list'], ',');
```